# Splitting text based on words in a list

Tags: python, web-scraping, split, text-analysis

I have a bunch of text documents from the congressional record of the senate. Speakers are identified by "Mr/Mrs/Ms. [name in all caps]." (note the period at the end). Basically there are lines starting with "Mr. REID." or some other senator to identify who is speaking. See [here for a full example](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/2011/10/20/senate-section/article/S6874-1).

For each document, I want to create a dictionary with keys {speaker: what they said}. If the same speaker is in the text twice, I want to just concatenate each time he spoke.

One idea was to split based on name, using a list of all senator names. Originally I was going to use something with isupper() to find where speaker changes, but this gets thrown of with names like McCONNELL.

Any thoughts?

Edit: To give a small example, consider this toy example

```
Mr. REID. Mr. President, thanks for whatever whatever

Mr. McCONNELL. I disagree yadda yaddaa yadaa

Mr. REID. I don't care 'bout yo Mitch

Mr. PAUL. Guyssssss
```

This should give a dictionary:

```
{"REID": "Mr. President, thanks for whatever whatever I don't care 'bout yo Mitch",
 "McCONNEL": "I disagree yadda yaddaa yadaa",
 "PAUL": "Guyssssss"}
```

Comment: `I want to just concatenate each time he spoke` - What to concatenate? Also, can you give a smaller example?

Comment: Say there is the case where the same speaker shows up multiple times. I want to combine what he says each time he talks into one string, and add that to the dictionary as dict[speaker] = everything he said

Comment: (Note that this isn't a problem, really. I know how to do that. I'm more concerned with how to properly split the text into chunks based on speaker, such that each chunk has a single speaker)

Comment: give an example to clarify yourself

Comment: Done. Should be clearer now. Note that this is a bit of an ideal case... the real text (see full example link) is going to be messier, so needs to be a pretty robust way of identifying speaker/text

Comment: I don't have time right now to write up a full example, but I would *first* create a list of all possible speakers. Process the data with something like: `[word for word in f.read() if mostly_uppercase(word)]` (define `mostly_uppercase` by using `sum(1 for lett in word if lett.isupper())` compared to `len(word)`, then use `re.split` to split on any of the occurrences of a name. This is two-step, but I don't think there's a cleaner way to handle it in the presence of non-all-cap names like `McCONNELL`

Comment: Another thing to note is when the text no longer correlates to a speaker's words. The presence of another speaker does not appear to be the only indicator that the current words no longer belong to the current speaker.

Comment: I agree, it's going to be messy to determine when someone is done talking. I figured the first step would be to split on speakers, then process those chunks looking for them quoting other people/bills/etc... but yeah, it will be messy.

Comment: @AdamSmith This is what I ended up doing -- if you write it up as a short answer, I'm more than happy to accept it!